# undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

the browser returned me the following error in Locals#show:

undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class

```
51: <%= form_for(@food) do |f| %>
52:   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
53:   <div class="field">
54:     <%= f.label :nome %>
```

Here is my locals_controller.rb (the show action)

```
 def show
   @local = Local.find(params[:id])
   @foods = @local.foods.paginate(page: params[:page])
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @local }
end
```

end

And here foods_controller.rb (the create action)

```
def create
@food = @local.foods.build(params[:food])
if @food.save
  flash[:success] = "Food created!"
  redirect_to '/locals'
else
  flash[:error] = "Error on creating food"
  render '/locals'
end
end
```

Food model and Local model are related with :has_many and belongs_to

What's the issue? Thank you

Comment: What is `@local` ? That sounds undefined.

Comment: @local = Local.find(params[:id])

Comment: you mean the scope of that variable is wrong?

Comment: You have `@food` in one controller action and `@foods` in another, yet the form is for `@food` (singular), and you say the error is for `Locals#show` where you use `@foods` (plural). Something doesn't match up there in your code.

Comment: i have @foods because i want to show in show.html.erb also a list of foods but the form is for a singular food so i don't understand

Comment: in form i have     @ food (singular for one food) in show i have     @foods in order to display a list of foods that belongs to a      local (in italian a synonim of "bar"). The     <%= form_for :food, :url => {:action => :create} do |f| %> solution seems to be working but raise another issue when i try to create a new food by filling fields and click on submit button i've been redirected to new Local path and no food has been created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then change your view code as:

```
<%= form_for :food, :url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
```

Comment: I've no more the error when page is displayed but when i try to create a new food by filling fields and click on submit button i've been redirected to new Local path and no food has been created, do you know why?

Comment: when i try to post the debugger writes the following : 
food: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  nome: a
  descrizione: ''
  prezzo: '10'
commit: Post
action: create
controller: locals ...How can i change the controller from locals to foods ?

Answer (score 2):

Check by adding following code (I assumed that your model is Local)
`@food = Local.new` 
In your new action

Comment: wait i have 2 model one is Local (that has_many :foods) and the other is Food (that belongs_to :local) so you mean @food = Food.new ?
However unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: You need to add this code in your 'show' action. Did you understand that your '@food' instance variable is not set in show action and that is why you are getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

If this happens while you EDIT, but it works while you CREATE

You must add a before action and set food

```
       before_action :set_food, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following code:

```
<%= form_for :food, :url => {:controller => :food, :action => :create} do |f| %>

<%= form_for :food, url: food_create_path do |f| %>


<%= form_for Food.new , url: food_create_path do |f| %>
```